# Drag a sprite to move another sprite

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm new to Phaser and have had no luck with looking at the documentation to solve my problem.

I'm creating a mobile game that will use touch(dragging) to move a player sprite. I want the user to able to be able see the player sprite when moving it, so I want to add a sprite for the sole purpose of controlling the player sprite.

The player sprite can only move left or right.
This is the code I have created so far, but it doesn't do what I want it to do

```
 var controller = game.add.sprite(0, scaleHeight(1150), cbox);
 game.physics.enable(controller, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
 controller.inputEnabled = true;
 controller.input.enableDrag(true);
 controller.input.allowHorizontalDrag = true;
 controller.input.allowVerticalDrag = false;
 controller.body.immovable = true;
 controller.body.moves = false;
 controller.events.onDragStart.add(doSomething, this);
```

The first problem is that the `Controller` sprite is moving when I drag it. The Second problem is that the location of the Player sprite is only moved the the location where I started dragging. It only moves to the click events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to override the `updateDrag` function.

```
controller.input.updateDrag = function(pointer) {
    player.x = pointer.x;
    // call the generic implementation:
    Phaser.InputHandler.prototype.updateDrag.call(this,pointer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in how to move a sprite using the drag input from another sprite without actually moving the dragged sprite (as I was when I found this question):

Here is an example using the drag input from a background sprite to move a player sprite:

```
var self = this;
this.background = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');
this.background.inputEnabled = true;
this.background.input.enableDrag();

this.player = this.add.sprite(this.world.centerX, this.world.centerY, 'player');
this.player.anchor.setTo(0.5);

this.background.input.startDrag = function(pointer) {
    pointer.playerStart = new Phaser.Point(self.player.x, self.player.y);
    Phaser.InputHandler.prototype.startDrag.call(this, pointer);
};
this.background.input.updateDrag = function(pointer) {
    self.player.x = pointer.playerStart.x - pointer.positionDown.x + pointer.x;
    self.player.y = pointer.playerStart.y - pointer.positionDown.y + pointer.y;
};
```

And if you want to keep the player within the bounds of the world:

```
var self = this;
this.background = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');
this.background.inputEnabled = true;
this.background.input.enableDrag();

this.player = this.add.sprite(this.world.centerX, this.world.centerY, 'player');
this.player.anchor.setTo(0.5);

this.background.input.startDrag = function(pointer) {
    pointer.playerStart = new Phaser.Point(self.player.x, self.player.y);
    Phaser.InputHandler.prototype.startDrag.call(this, pointer);
};
this.background.input.updateDrag = function(pointer) {
    self.player.x = pointer.playerStart.x - pointer.positionDown.x + pointer.x;
    self.player.y = pointer.playerStart.y - pointer.positionDown.y + pointer.y;
    if (self.player.x > self.world.width){
        self.player.x = pointer.playerStart.x = self.world.width;
        pointer.positionDown.x = pointer.x;
    }
    if (self.player.y > self.world.height){
        self.player.y = pointer.playerStart.y = self.world.height;
        pointer.positionDown.y = pointer.y;
    }
    if (self.player.x < 0){
        self.player.x = pointer.playerStart.x = 0;
        pointer.positionDown.x = pointer.x;
    }
    if (self.player.y < 0){
        self.player.y = pointer.playerStart.y = 0;
        pointer.positionDown.y = pointer.y;
    }
};
```

I am new the Phaser, so I am not sure if there is a better way of doing this, but it is working for me, so I thought I'd share!